# Django staff users closed groups

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-filters, django-admin-tools

I'm developing a django project for small organizations.
The organization can register to the site (marked as staff user by site admin), create new users and new services for other registered members. Members can register, login and see what the organization put in their profiles.

**Now the problem is that if another organization register to the site, after marked as staff user it will see and can manage members created by other organization registered to the site.**

I would like to let any organization registered manage its own members only and hide other organizations registered too.

How can this be done?

Comment: you can use the id of the organization so that they will just see where group they belong

Comment: thank you @catherine the problem is that when organization does the login and access django-admin backend it see other registered users and organization, how can I do this "id" filter? ps - I would like to ask you a private question how can I do here? in your blog there is no contact infos.

Comment: maybe this can help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310983/django-admin-specific-user-admin-content

Comment: you can send a message on my gmail

Comment: @catherine thank you very much!! I will check that post you suggested later and accept your answer! thank you

Comment: I checked the post but It seems too risky because organizations will use the same backend as admin and playing with URLs can have access to other organizations data, and I will need to modify django native code too (and I don't like to do that). What about building another backend only for organizations? is it hard to do? where can I start? is there any docs?

Comment: @catherine this is another useful post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821418/using-django-admin-and-a-custom-user-specific-admin-concurrently?rq=1) but no solution is provided.

Comment: I remember my boss create an extra admin in one of his app. Why not create another admin? What do you think?

Comment: I think that if we solve this we'll be able to make any django application for small organizations, shops and groups, please help. This will be very useful and high demanded.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very busy in my site because it's not stable yet. I need to prioritize that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2008/dec/24/admin/
at the end he explains how to display objects in the admin site only to objects owners.